# Time Out Error in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, connection-timeout, command-timeout

How can I stop time out error for executing SQL query in ASP.Net?
I researched in Google but I couldn't solve my problem correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is about ***CommandTimeOut***.The time (in seconds) to wait for the command to execute. The default is 30 seconds. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is full example. Otherwise, you should set the ***ConnectionTimeOut*** in your database connection string. Something like that

```
<add key="ConnString2" value="Provider=SQLOLEDB;User Id=sa;PASSWORD=1;
SERVER=BlurBlur;database=BlurBlur;Connect Timeout=60;"/>
```

---

If you use the ***UpdatePanel***, set the ***AsyncPostBackTimeout***.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" 
AsyncPostBackTimeout ="360000"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

---

to be more sure

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="360000"/>
```

Comment: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerTimeoutException: The server request timed out.
This is the error Message

Answer (score 0):

Please consider you have 2 timeout to deal with when you access database via ADO.net

```
ConnectionTimeout
```

set in connection string: it's the time in seconds asp.net will time out in opening a connection

and

```
CommandTimeout

es: SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandTimeout = .....;
```

it's the time in seconds the sql command will timeout.

Stefano